# Change element display property by hovering its sibling

Tags: html, css

I have a menu links and by default one of them is hidden. I'm trying to change its display when hovering some other menu link.

HTML:

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hover me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">I'm here</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}
ul li:nth-child(2):hover ~ ul li:nth-child(3) {
    display: block;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `ul` from your selector, since you've already selected the `ul` at the start -> `ul li:nth-child(2):hover`. Moreover, using `display: block;` will change the `display` of the list item so I've modified that for you

```css
ul li:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}
ul li:nth-child(2):hover ~ li:nth-child(3) {
    display: list-item;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hover me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">I'm here</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that if you have more items in the list, all will show up at once, so in order to fix that, you can use the adjacent selector instead of a sibling like `ul li:nth-child(2):hover + li`

---

Also, user will never be able to click this link if you move hover out from the menu item, in this case, you need to nest the menu items in the UL